# "denial in discussion until full knowledge" fallacy

Tags: fallacies

Is this a fallacy, to forbid any discussion until the opposing side is completely familiar with the basis for your arguments? And deny any counterarguments as caused by ignorance. If it is, what is the correct term for it?

Examples:

> You can't discuss this topic until you know all the basis for each side's arguments.

> You can't argue with this paper until you've read all the research it cited.

> You can't condemn war crimes until you are familiar with each side's propaganda.

> To discuss Christianity, atheists must first read all related religious texts. And if they are still not convinced, they are not immersed enough and need to continue studying.

> You must study all these books by flat-earthers before trying to prove that the Earth is round.

> You can't argue for vaccination until you study all these controversial papers which argue against.

Comment: Is this is about global warming or vaccines?  The fallacy is imagining you can argue with the experts on a legitimate hard-science subject, when you yourself are not any kind of expert in the field.  Facebook is not Harvard, science is *complicated*, and it is easy for someone to be misled if they are unfamiliar with the depth of the field, or even just how statistics and the scientific method work.

Comment: It is a form of [argument from authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority), which is not a fallacy when the authority in question is the consensus among scientists in a hard scientific field, about that field.

Comment: Yes, now I see how this relates to the arguments anti-vaxxers or flat-earthers make. The premise for this question is quite delicate and deals with topics such as religion and hate crimes. Therefore, I've tried to provide more neutral examples, not to trigger anyone and to comply with the community guidelines.

Comment: Well, whether it's fallacious or not depends on the context.  There are fields, such as mathematics, where the average person would need years of training just to read and understand one paper, and until they have that training they can't give any meaningful opinions.  There are other fields, such as sociology, that are less "deep" where the concepts in a paper are closer to an average person's experience.  (Although, the average person does not know the statistics used in sociology either, or much of the terminology.)  So you can't provide "neutral" examples - it depends on the exact context.

Comment: I've added additional examples with similar patterns. Is it still an appeal to authority when instead of saying "statement is true 'cause the book says so" you argue that "you can't say statement is false until you study this supplementary material", when in some cases the supplementary material is virtually infinite?

Comment: Well, it depends on the supplementary material and how truly required it is, to have an opinion.  So you're relying on the authority of the supplementary material.  If the supplementary material is a legitimate authority without which you cannot understand the subject, it may be required reading.

Comment: But if we consider fallacious case, it still supposes that statement could be proven false. However, in order to prove it false, the more and more strict conditions need to be met, to the point that they are virtually impossible. While in the canonical definition of appeal to authority, the authority is considered true in any case.

Comment: It could be a [perfectionist fallacy](http://philosophyreaders.blogspot.com/2019/05/perfectionist-fallacies.html), "argument that if some solution to a problem doesn't solve the problem perfectly, then that solution is unacceptable". But whether it is or not turns on what the counterarguments are. If they only work because of something the arguer did not take into account due to lack of familiarity a rebuke is in order. But it is more constructive to point out a specific fault instead of issuing blanket demand for perfection.

Answer (score 2):

### It Depends

Sometimes, this is entirely justified; there is no value in having a discussion with someone if **you're not sharing at least some referential framework.**

For example, if I wanted to talk about some calculus with somebody, and they barely know any maths, it would be justified to defer the conversation until they understand more of the referential framework. Without that, **neither of us can extract any value from the conversation.**

However, sometimes this is unjustified. Your example around the Flat Earth is a good one; we have superb first-hand evidence now that the Earth is, in fact, an oblate spheroid.

A Flat Earther telling you that you have to read the literature is not saying it because you don't share a referential framework, because you do; by virtue of standing on Earth, especially in the modern era of planes and satellites, you have the information you need.

Instead, they are **denying the validity** of your framework, your knowledge and your arguments; this is an **appeal to authority**, warped by strange views on the concept of authority, which makes it hard to spot.

They are saying, "your information isn't good enough, **and mine is, because X.**"

The "Because X" is where the fallacy sits in this argument; there's nothing fallacious about skepticism in your interlocutor's information.

As it's an X, anything can go here; different logical fallacies fit just as well. It's just that in the circumstances you describe, the problem is a (deeply flawed) appeal to authority.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just call the example statements false rather than fallacies. Fallacies are faulty inferences, but the examples are statements, not inferences. Inferences can be fallacious; statements can be false. All of the example statements deserve a response of "Why not?" (I agree with the answerer who said it would fall under the category of argument from authority. Also agree with the answerer with the calculus example, that sometimes there's a legit point to such a point. But asking "Why not?" supplants the presumption of the proposition's truth with the process of figuring out whether the proposition is true.